# Queue Connection Instantiated?

Tags: java, queue, jms, message

I'm doing an example of a message queue. When I look at the documentation, QueueConnection is an interface, but it's being instantiated in sample code. How is this possible? I know it extends the Connection interface. All explanations would be nice to help further my knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to focus on a very specific part of your question

> QueueConnection is an interface, but it's being instantiated in sample code

Consider the following code :

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyInterface myVar = new MyInterface(){ 
            public void myMethod(){ 
                System.out.println("hello World"); 
            }
        };
        myVar.myMethod();
    }

    private interface MyInterface{
        void myMethod(); 
    }
}
```

Basically an interface is a contract and any class that instantiates it must fulfill the contract. If you can write an anonymous class you can make it appear as though you'e instantiated the interface.

You can even do something like this (Although it serves no purpose)

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyInterface myVar = new MyInterface(){ };
    }

    private interface MyInterface{ }
}
```

You can see more about this here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Took me a minute to grasp the semantics, but it makes sense now. I'm instantiating QueueConnection from a QueueConnectionFactory method. I guess the fulfilling of the "contract" is going on behind the scenes. The documentation was VERY helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure of your specific case some code might be helpful.

In case you inject this resource in EJB then the object may be pointed with the interface.

The other way you get a handle to a connection object is when you call createConnection() method. in this case the object will eventually be of the same type as the interface.

But to your point you never use new QueueConnection().

For more details see this example design pattern on how object can be referenced to the interface http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm (can be used for any java interface)

Comment: The diagram was very helpful, I'm still wrapping my head around it. Basically, you're creating an object from an interface because the methods have been implemented, therefore no rules have been broken.